# zend locale with url routing

Tags: zend-framework, url, routes, locale

Is there a simple way of using zend routes and  locales in the URL to force the loading of a particular locale?

e.g. - http://domain.com/en-US/controller1/action

So the language-Region should prefix all URL calls and just set the locale in the bootstrap but let the rest of the MVC routing work as normal.

ideally it could detect if no language-Region is in the URL and attempt to autodetect from the browser.

e.g. - http://domain.com/ (if no locale is found - defaults  to en-US/index)

I've seen some articles on routes for things like custom user vanity urls.  e.g. - http://domain.com/username (routes to http://domain.com/user/load/username)

To me it seems like it should be similar to this, but I was wondering if there's something more elegant?

Thanks,

Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont want to copy over all the sourcecode, so have a look at

- [Zend Framework Best Practices – Part 2: I18n](http://joegornick.com/2009/12/02/zend-framework-best-practices-part-2-i18n) and
- [Chaining language with default route](https://devzone.zend.com/1765/chaining-language-with-default-route/)

Comment: thanks for those, found all the information I needed.  It would be nice if the Zend FW included this.

Comment: exactly my thoughts AndreLiem... can't find 1 concrete solution to what I'm looking for. I can't believe there are multiple ways of doing this. It should just be a part of ZF. www.website.com/en/controller/action/ - The whole application should either be in one language or the other. I don't see why there are a solutions that have stuff like www.website.com/controller/en/action