# Zend Framework 1.x, how to add language prefix at URI?

Tags: php, zend-framework, multilingual

I am building multi-language site with ZendFramework.

Regarding to URL , I want it like :

http://example.com/lang/module/controller/action

Yes, I create new router at _initRoute() in bootstrap.php :

```
public function _initRoutes() {
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $this->_frontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');
    $router = $this->_frontController->getRouter();

    $langRouter = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/', array(
        'lang' => 'en'
    ));

    $defaultRouter = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':module/:controller/:action', array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
    ));

    $defaultRouter = $langRouter->chain($defaultRouter);

    $router->addRoute('langRoute', $langRouter);
    $router->addRoute('defaultRoute', $defaultRouter);

}
```

it really works.

but it is not complete, I have two problems :

1. how to setup default language
   ex, if URL is

   http://example.com/module/controller/action

   the _initRoutes() only treat "module" as language
2. how to generate URL in language ?

   something like:

   $this->url(array('controller' => '', 'module' => '', 'action' => '', 'lang' => ''))

Can you help me to solve the problem ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137391/zend-locale-with-url-routing